# How to add the menu items using android navigation component

Tags: android, menuitem, android-navigation

I'm trying to add a menu to the the toolbar of the application

My app is based on **single-activity multi-fragment**

and I'm using the navigation component my app style is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and I'm configuring the grapp in the MainActivity's onCreate method like that:

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
```

My question is how to add different custom menu items for the different fragments?
also, I have added the back button how to handle it's clicks and hide it on the first fragment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seems to have it setup correctly. Please make sure your fragments have `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` (can be under `onViewCreated`) and that you are actually inflating menus under `onCreateOptionsMenu` of your fragments. Important to note your fragments title will be managed based on nav location (what is specified under `android:label`)